# How to get the index of particular string from custom arraylist

Tags: java, android

I want to get the index of the value  that function return me but it is giving me only -1 value.

```
ArrayList<categoryoptions_class> arrayList;
rb = new RadioButton[arrayList.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                rb[i] = new RadioButton(detail_activity_rb.this);
                rb[i].setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                rb[i].setId(arrayList.get(i).getId());
                rb[i].setTag(arrayList.get(i).getValue());
                rb[i].setText(arrayList.get(i).getCategory_opt_name());

                String a = checkdata(cat_id, rb[i].getId(), i);
// this 'a' is returning perfect value but when i am trying to get the index of the value in a it gives me only -1; 

int sa = Arrays.asList(arrayList).indexOf(a);
Toast.makeText(detail_activity_rb.this, sa + " :val", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //  int sa = i;
                if (i == sa) {
                    rb[i].setChecked(true);
                }

                rg.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                rg.addView(rb[i]);
                checkpos(i,i);
}

 public String checkdata(int cat_ids, int optids, int ia) {
    String a = cat_ids + "";
    String b = optids + "";
    String c  = ia + "";
    String aa = a + b;
    Cursor cursor;
   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),aa,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(cat_type.equals("rb1"))
    {
         cursor = dbController.getdata("SELECT * FROM store_values WHERE catopt_id = '"+cat_ids+"';");
    }
    else
    {
         cursor = dbController.getdata("SELECT * FROM store_values WHERE catopt_id = '"+aa+"';");
    }

    //   arrayList.clear();
    if (cursor.getCount() != 0)
    {
        String val = "";
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            val = cursor.getString(8);
        }
        //Toast.makeText(detail_activity_rb.this,"H",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return val;
    }
    else
    {
        return "not";
    }

}
```

Comment: Why does every new java programmer start and name his variables a, b, c, ... what I am saying is: you write code so that **humans** can read and understand it. You use variable names that **mean** something, so that the reader understands what the variable is about. You not doing that ... makes it 10 times harder to read your code than it ought to be.

Comment: And: `ArrayList<categoryoptions_class> arrayList;` ... rather do `List<categoryoptions_class> categoryClasses = new ArrayList<>();` or so.

Comment: Finally: also follow java naming conventions. Class names should go UpperCamelCase, so categoryoptions_class should better read CategoryOptions ... and if course, that name also confuses readers. Are you talking about instances of java.lang.Class, or does your _class relate to some "classification" within your business logic. I could go on and and on here. I hope you see how much the way you write your code impacts your readers. Learning to do that in reasonable ways is thus really really important.

Comment: I wouldnt call that approach "correct". Yes, it works, but it is far from I would accept in a code review ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your arraylist is of categoryoptions_class type but what you want to get through index of is a string so it will obviously return -1 (not found).Here is something you can tyr:

- If your  categoryoptions_class contains a data member of string type
  and you want to compare the object that matches with this data member
  then iterate over the arraylist and access that data member of each
  object then breakout when matches else print -1.
- Else if your
  categoryoptions_class doesn't compare any data member as string then
  you will need to construct an object of categoryoptions_class and
  then you can use indexOf option.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
int sa = Arrays.asList(arrayList).indexOf(a);
```

That simply doesn't make sense. That `arrayList` is declared as:

```
ArrayList<categoryoptions_class> arrayList;
```

So, what you are doing is: turning a `ArrayList<categoryoptions_class>` into a `List<ArrayList<categoryoptions_class>>`. And then you ask that list whether it contains a **string**.

A list of lists of something for sure will **not** contain a String object.

Unfortunately the rest of your code is so *confusing* that I feel unable to tell you how exactly you have to "search" on your `arrayList` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index= 0;
                    for (categoryoptions_class categoryoptions_class : arrayList) {
                        if (categoryoptions_class.getCategory_opt_name().equals(a)) {
                            index= arrayList.indexOf(categoryoptions_class);
                            Log.d("Position", mArrayList.indexOf(products) + "");

                        }

                    }
```

Comment: Hint: when you really want the first index, then do not use for-each. Simply use a normal "counting" loop: `for (i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) { if arrayList.get(i).equals .... then log/break }`. Your approach is neither efficient, nor easy to read/understand.